# MySQL delete row with AJAX and JSON failed

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I try to DELETE a row in mysql. I got help to insert and it works well. I tried to use the same logic for delete one row with ID identification, but I can not delete the row.

What is wrong in this code?

...

Here is the full code:

Javascript:

```
function jsRecordDeleteWrite()
{

    var jsObject = {
        "ID": document.form_articles.ID.value
    };

    // ... the AJAX request is successful
    var updatePage = function (response) {
        alert("record successful deleted");
    };
    // ... the AJAX request fail
    var printError = function (req, status, err) {
        alert("deletingt record failed");
    };
    // Create an object to describe the AJAX request
    $.ajax({
        url        : 'deletearticle.php',
        dataType   : 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        data       : jsObject,
        type       : 'POST',
        success: updatePage,
        error: printError
    });
  }
```

Here is deletearticle.php

```
<?php

 $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin0', 'star1star1star0');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('sob', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

//read the json file contents
$ID =  $_POST['ID'];

//delete item from mysql table
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM articles WHERE ID=$ID");

if(!mysql_query($sql))
{
die('Error : ' . mysql_error());
}

//database connection close
mysql_close($link);

//}

?>
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: stop using `mysql_` it is deprecated! use mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the server receives in php

```
var_dump($ID);
```

If query is right, check the mysql user has rights to update table

Comment: $id = $_POST['ID'];


    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM articles WHERE id < ".$id."");

Is this correct? Any  help  is very much appreciated !!!

Comment: I checked yesterday the rights of the user, and it was ok. If I use PhpMyAdmin, I can delete and edit data, but when I send the code with Ajax and JSON and PHP I can not perform EDIT and DELETE, but Insert Into works.

Comment: Mayby set
`$id = intval($_POST['ID']);`
and add quotes
`$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM \`articles\` WHERE ID='$ID'");`

is isset ID field in table articles?

In Google Chrome press ctrl+shift+j you may see the reqest in network tab

Comment: I can not tell you with words what a feeling I have. I have to say to you the biggest thank  you that I ever said to somebody.

Your answer was on the spot 100% correct.

I wish you all the best and may the sun  shine  always over you!!!!!!

You have no idea how  much you helped me  with it.  I stuck since 4 days on it and did not know what to do.


THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put single quotes around `$ID`:

```
//delete item from mysql table
$sql = mysql_query("DELETE FROM articles WHERE ID= '$ID'");
```